# removing Wordpress from the url is not possible

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have migrated a Wordpress and I must use https://myweb.com/wordpress
otherwise it does not direct me to the web. so I search and I found few solutions

the most resonable one was to change the address of the site in setting and general
basically just remove the /wordpress/ and then replace the following in the index.php

```
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I did both when I go to https://myweb.com/ it gives me like the page is a test
and when I go to https://myweb.com/wordpress , it says Error 500

note that I dont have .htaccess file, so I created it manually but if it is there or not , it seems like it does not matter and yes of course I went to permalinks and and click on post name and save and yes I checked if it is hidden and was not so I created a basic one and I put this in it

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and these are the only files I have now

```
index.php                  wp-comments-post.php  wp-login.php
license.txt                wp-config.php         wp-mail.php
php.php                    wp-config-sample.php  wp-settings.php
logo_small.png              wp-content            wp-signup.php
readme.html                wp-cron.php           wp-trackback.php
wp-activate.php            wp-includes           xmlrpc.php
wp-admin                   wp-links-opml.php
wp-blog-header.php         wp-load.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change the siteurl field and home field in the wp_options table, in the obtion_name row.
Your site should be in the root directory of your account and not in wordpress dir.
You can also define as a constant siteurl in wp-config.php

Try these, maybe it will help.

Comment: I dont see any wp_options, I added whatever files I have there

Comment: and I changed the wp_config.php but the same error